# Is the Intel Core 2 Duo E7400 2.80 GHz CPU 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: cpu, desktop-computer

I have just updated my pc to Windows 10 and noticed in the settings the system type is :
32 bit operating system,x64-based processor

From past 6 yrs I have this computer and while buying it was said it is 32 bit . I want to know whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit processor
On Intel webpage it's written x64 bit instructions 
I have intel core(TM) 2 duo cpu E7400 @ 2.80GHz 
Please help!

Comment: If you've got less than 4GB of RAM then there is no problem with 32-bit, if you have 4GB or more and have just updated to Windows 10 then you could take the time to get your product key and do a clean install of Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: I have 2gb ram so should I update to 64 bit Windows 10

Comment: @Mokubai But even with a 32 bit system, more than 4 GiB of RAM can be used (this is called PAE) - just not in a single linear way. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Comment: @dcmotor with only 2GB I'd stick with 32-bit, unless you're looking to upgrade it soon.

Comment: @Shi, you *can* but not all old mobos support the memory remapping needed to make use of 4GB properly in 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

It sais [here](http://ark.intel.com/m/nl/products/36500/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7400-3M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) it has a 64-bit instruction set. So: the Intel E7400 is a 64 bit processor.

Comment: So from past 6 yrs like a fool I had Windows 32bit and all apps to with 32 bit

Comment: So does this reduce the performance on my cpu

Comment: It seems like that's the case. Although I think in general, with "normal end-user computing, you won't notice much difference. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378399/are-64-bit-programs-bigger-and-faster-than-32-bit-versions) Stack Overflow Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I just searched the web for it and the [Intel product database](http://ark.intel.com/products/36500/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7400-3M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) said:

```
Instruction Set: 64-bit
```

So, it is a 64 bit CPU.